# ¿Cómo crear registros de una base de datos ACCESS desde un UserForm de macro en excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access

muy buenas
Estoy aprendiendo a usar macros en excel con visual basic y me encontré con un problema, no sé como utilizar el recordset y no se como guardar datos, ¿me podrían ayudar por favor?

Este es el código del módulo donde creo la conexion

```
Public miConexion As New ADODB.Connection
Public Rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Sub Conecta()
Set miConexion = New ADODB.Connection
    With miConexion
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Calendario\BBDD\Calendario.accdb"
        .Open
    End With
End Sub

Sub abrirMenu()
Load Menu
Menu.Show
End Sub
```

Y este es el código del form donde trato de almacenar los datos

```
Private Sub btnIngresarNivel_Click()
Call Conecta
If miConexion.State = 1 Then
Set Rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Rs.Open miConexion
   Rs.AddNew
    Rs.Fields("Nivel") = cmbNiveles.Text
    Rs.Fields("Jornada") = cmbJornadas.Text
    Rs.Fields("Horas") = txtHorasSemanales.Text
    Rs.Update
    MsgBox "Registro Guardado correctamente"
End If
End Sub
```

Gracias por tu tiempo y por tu ayuda, saludos

Comment: Tu objeto `RS` lo estás definiendo como un nuevo Recordset, pero tú quieres guardar la info en una tabla. Tendrás que asociar el Recordset a la tabla donde quieres guardar la info, probablemente con una consulta SQL supongo.

Comment: Probablemente algo como `SELECT NombreTabla.Nivel, NombreTabla.Jornada, NombreTabla.Horas
FROM NombreTabla;` te deje asociar el RS a tu tabla, y entonces tu código debería funcionar.